# Best way to convert numerical columns of a dataset with missing values into a matrix

Tags: matrix, dataset

What is the best way (simplest, fastest) to convert the numerical columns of a dataset into a matrix? The numerical columns can have missing values.

For example for this dataset:

```
ds = Dataset@{<|"passengerClass" -> "3rd", "passengerAge" -> 36.5`, 
"passengerSex" -> "male", "passengerSurvival" -> "survived", 
"passengerWeight" -> 186.5`|>, <|"passengerClass" -> "3rd", 
"passengerAge" -> 9.`, "passengerSex" -> "female", 
"passengerSurvival" -> "survived", 
"passengerWeight" -> 90.`|>, <|"passengerClass" -> "1st", 
"passengerAge" -> 35.`, "passengerSex" -> "male", 
"passengerSurvival" -> "survived", 
"passengerWeight" -> Missing[]|>, <|"passengerClass" -> "1st", 
"passengerAge" -> 60.`, "passengerSex" -> "male", 
"passengerSurvival" -> "survived", 
"passengerWeight" -> 160.`|>, <|"passengerClass" -> "3rd", 
"passengerAge" -> 23.`, "passengerSex" -> "female", 
"passengerSurvival" -> "survived", 
"passengerWeight" -> Missing[]|>, <|"passengerClass" -> "3rd", 
"passengerAge" -> 22.`, "passengerSex" -> "female", 
"passengerSurvival" -> "survived", 
"passengerWeight" -> 122.`|>, <|"passengerClass" -> "3rd", 
"passengerAge" -> Missing[], "passengerSex" -> "female", 
"passengerSurvival" -> "survived", 
"passengerWeight" -> 120|>, <|"passengerClass" -> "3rd", 
"passengerAge" -> Missing[], "passengerSex" -> "female", 
"passengerSurvival" -> "survived", 
"passengerWeight" -> Missing[]|>, <|"passengerClass" -> "1st", 
"passengerAge" -> 17.`, "passengerSex" -> "female", 
"passengerSurvival" -> "survived", "passengerWeight" -> 170.`|>}
```

[image]

This does not work:

```
ds[All, Select[NumberQ]][Values]
```

[image]

Some clarifying points follow.

- I would like the `_Missing` entries to be replaced with $0$'s.
- I do not know in advance the columns of interest. I want to pick the numerical columns of the dataset and then make a matrix with them.

(If I knew how to replace the missing values in a dataset with $0$s I would have solved this problem already.)

Comment: Like this? `Query[Values, Select[NumericQ]][ds]` or your expression with `NumericQ` instead of `NumberQ`.

Comment: Ahh, I guess your real question is how you can convert the `Missing` to a number to make a complete matrix.

Comment: @halirutan "how you can convert the Missing to a number to make a complete matrix." Correct.

Comment: Can't you just do `ds /. _Missing->0`?

Comment: @CarlWoll Of course. Combining your answer with @halirutan I came up with `Query[All, Values@*Select[NumberQ]]@ ReplaceAll[Normal[ds2], _Missing -> 0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Normal @ ds[All, Values@*Select[NumericQ]@*ReplaceAll[_Missing->0]]
```

> {{36.5, 186.5}, {9., 90.}, {35., 0}, {60., 160.}, {23., 0}, {22., 
>     122.}, {0, 120}, {0, 0}, {17., 170.}}

Comment: Right, very similar to my response to Carl Woll in the comments yesterday: `Query[All, Values@*Select[NumberQ]]@ ReplaceAll[Normal[ds2], _Missing -> 0]`.  I end up using that line in my package code, so I am going to accept this answer.

Answer (score 6):

It's not entirely clear if you want to replace the rows that contain a `Missing` or if you want to leave them out. When you want to leave them out, the very verbose way would be to write it out like this:

```
Query[
  Select[!MissingQ[#"passengerAge"] && ! MissingQ[#"passengerWeight"] &], 
  {#"passengerAge", #"passengerWeight"} &
][ds]
```

and then normalizing.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`Query` is not strictly necessary, but due to the good advertisement of WReach, I learned to prefer it. This is possible too

```
ds[Select[! MissingQ[#"passengerAge"] && !MissingQ[#"passengerWeight"] &],
 {#"passengerAge", #"passengerWeight"} &]
```

### Edit

> Thank you for your answer! Preferably, I would like the `Missing` to be replaced by 0's.

Then probably:

```
Query[ReplaceAll[Missing[] -> 0], {#"passengerAge", #"passengerWeight"} &][ds]
```

Comment: I like the use of `Query` too.

Answer (score 6):

This works:

```
Block[{Missing},
 Missing[] = 0;
 ds[All, Select[NumberQ]][Values]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
ds[associationIndex][Transpose][
  GroupBy[Query[DeleteMissing /* Query[Apply[And], NumericQ]]] /* 
   Query[{Key[True] -> Query[All, All, Replace[_Missing -> 0.]]}] /* 
   Values /* Apply[Join]][Transpose]
```

[image]

Where the utility `associationIndex` is one of dozens one-liners included in the API of my forthcoming book "Functional Data Workflow".

```
associationIndex[a_Association]:=Query[Normal/*MapIndexed[First[#2]->#1&]/*Association][a]

associationIndex[l_List]:=Query[MapIndexed[First[#2]->#1&]/*Association][l]
```

Without it, after the `Apply[Join]` you'd have to thread keys back in - note the use of bracketing `Transpose`. Such commutation is a common pattern, (btw `Transpose` will also impute `Missing` values to normalize ragged data.) - but careful as the op-form is buggy (I avoided `RightComposition`)

You might want to mod the logic below to suit various applications:

`Query[DeleteMissing /* Query[Apply[And], NumericQ]]`

If you just want the numeric matrix, there's no need for the Join:

```
ds[associationIndex][Transpose][
  GroupBy[Query[DeleteMissing /* Query[Apply[And], NumericQ]]] /* 
   Key[True] /* 
   Query[Values, Values, Replace[_Missing -> 0.]]][Transpose]
```

> {{36.5, 186.5}, {9., 90.}, {35., 0.}, {60., 160.}, {23., 0.}, {22., 
>     122.}, {0., 120}, {0., 0.}, {17., 170.}}

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just pick the columns of interest, and then replace the missing objects?

```
ReplaceAll[_Missing->0]@Values@ds[All, {"passengerAge","passengerWeight"}]
```

[image]

Comment: "Can't you just pick the columns of interest, and then replace the missing objects?" -- Generally, I do not know in advance the columns of interest. I want to pick the numerical columns of the dataset and then make a matrix with them.